# How to change the name of the app on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, icons, rename

I did this before, but can't remember it now.

I want to change what appears under the icon of my app on the home screen.  Where in Xcode do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in your info.plist file (included in your xcode project). The Key is "Bundle display name"

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As implied by the fact that "Bundle display name" is usually $(PRODUCT_NAME), you should actually set the "Product Name" build setting in your Target's build setting, for all configurations, and let it propagate to all the places that depend on it.

Comment: This is correct -- always change the variable value, that way every place that uses it gets updated correctly.